# If earth generates magnetic field does it attract metal?

Tags: magnetic-fields, earth, weight

If earth generates magnetic field does it attract metal objects at the surface of the planet and make them heavier?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are metals more heavy due to the Earth's magnetic field?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/100086/)